# Web based compiler

Tags: php, c++, html, c

I have been working on project, to make a website which read files(c/c++ text file) and compile the code written on it.

How can I use compiler which is on my server?

Comment: Side note: you'll face several security issues as you will launch your compiler on an user input.

Comment: Check out [Codepad](http://codepad.org/about) to see how they are doing it.

Comment: An alternative would be to translate the code into something like JavaScript and run it on the client. And you can write the translator in that same JavaScript and run it on the client as well. Benefits: fewer security issues to take care of, lower server load. Drawbacks: limited C code, slower "compilation" and execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$_POST['CODE']` contains the cpp code. You can do the following.

```
$code = do_sanitizing($_POST['CODE']);
$filename = "cfile".time().".c";
// put the contents in a file
file_put_contents($filename, $code);
// compile it
$output = system("/usr/bin/gcc $filename  2>&1");
echo $output;
```

**Note:** This type of compiling and running programs afterwards has dangerous security flaws.

1. You must sanitize user input
2. The C source code may crash the compiling process
3. The output program might contain code that is dangerous to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Use the compiler in your OS. In Linux, you could use gcc, for example. You can run from PHP, using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: Please give me more details!!

Comment: What are you interested in?
As far as I'm concerned, you use GCC for C code compilation, G++ for C++. GCC man page - http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc.
Of course it's completely different, if your server runs on Windows. You can specify server OS for a start, to get more specific answers.

Comment: Actually I want to integrate my website, which is in php,and c++ compilerand by just one button click the whole code written in my uploaded text file should compiled. The only result display  on my website is whether it is correct or incorrect?

Comment: You can stick to the code, that **Shiplu** gave upwards. Then just check $output, if it contains any error messages. I believe, GCC sends errors to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has `system()` and `exec()` functions. Maybe those are what you're looking for?